# how to make this static

Tags: android, andar

```
public static Bitmap bmp;
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.nehe);
```

the error for above code "Syntax error on token ";", , expected" I already put a semi colon after `bmp` but still the error occurs

here is the full code:

```
public class CustomActivity extends AndARActivity {

ARToolkit artoolkit;
CustomObject someObject;
CustomObject1 someObject1;


public static Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.nehe);  


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CustomRenderer renderer = new CustomRenderer();     

    super.setNonARRenderer(renderer);

    try {
        //register a object for each marker type
        artoolkit = super.getArtoolkit();

        someObject = new CustomObject
            ("test", "androidpirate.patt", 80.0, new double[]{0,0});
        artoolkit.registerARObject(someObject);

        someObject = new CustomObject
        ("test", "andson.patt", 80.0, new double[]{0,0});
        artoolkit.registerARObject(someObject);

        someObject1 = new CustomObject1("test","andrev.patt", 80.0, new double[]{0,0});
        artoolkit.registerARObject(someObject1);

        someObject1 = new CustomObject1("test","androidpat.patt", 80.0, new double[]{0,0});
        artoolkit.registerARObject(someObject1);

    } catch (AndARException ex){
        //handle the exception, that means: show the user what happened
        System.out.println("");
    }       
    startPreview();
}


@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
    Log.e("AndAR EXCEPTION", ex.getMessage());
    finish();
}   
}
```

Comment: once build the project and clean it

Comment: public declarations can be used only for class variables not for function variables.

Answer (score 1):

`public` declarations can be used only for class variables not for function variables

Answer (score 1):

You are calling "this" in a static context, "this" refers to the class *instance object*, therefore using it in a static manner is not a valid Java syntax. Additionally, I don't think "this.getResources()" would return anything but null until the time onCreate(Bundle) method is called.

You should do something like:

```
public static Bitmap bmp;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(bmp!=null) {
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.nehe);
    }
...other code here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Bitmap bmp =
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.nehe);
```

or

```
public static Bitmap bmp;

static {
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.nehe);
}
```

Comment: sir I already did the first and I try the second lately but still the error is "Cannot use this in a static context"

Comment: I already edit my post and I pasted the full source of the class customactivity sir

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing those statements in a method, then `public` is not a valid access modifier for local variables.

If you are writing those statements outside a method within a class, then those statements should be combined as follows:

```
public Bitmap bmp = 
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.nehe);
```

This is because, only initializers are allowed outside methods or blocks, but not assignment statements like your second statement.

Since you seem to have a dependency on the return value of `getResources()` member method, bmp cannot be static. Also, it is better to initialize bmp only when you are sure that the return value of `getResources()` method is meaningful. You should show more code from your class to get better help w.r.t this.

Comment: I already did this lately but this error will occur "Cannot use this in a static context"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that you were using `this.getResources()`. You cannot use member methods or member variables in a static context. Here too, bmp should be a member variable if it depends on the return value of `getResources()` for a given object.

Comment: I already edit my post and show to full code of class customactivity